# Django- template loop but exclude repeats

Tags: python, django, templates

Say I have this data and I'm passing to my template:

```
apps = [
 {'category': 'one', 'item': 'blah'},
 {'category': 'one', 'item': 'blah'},
 {'category': 'two', 'item': 'blah'},
 {'category': 'two', 'item': 'blah'},
 {'category': 'three', 'item': 'blah'}
]
```

Then in my template I want to add one div withe the id 'category' but not repeat any divs if they've been added before with the id. So something similar to:

```
{% for app in apps %}
   <div id="{{app.category}}"></div>
{% endfor %}
```

But I only want these to be rendered:

```
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
```

Comment: I think it will be much easier to adjust the data in your view before passing to the template.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should remove duplicates before pass your apps list to template.

There's plenty of ways to do so, and I'll give simple example.

`apps = [dict(t) for t in set([tuple(d.items()) for d in apps])]`

#### Update

If you want to del your `{'items': 'blah'}` in `apps`, I recommend del that key, value pair before making new apps.

You can just use simple `del` function with for loop like this

```
for d in apps:
    del d['item']
```

then your `apps` list will be like this

```
[{'category': 'one'},
 {'category': 'one'},
 {'category': 'two'},
 {'category': 'two'},
 {'category': 'three'}]
```

Then you can use my answer again.

> If you are familiar with `lambda`, you can use lambda function like this

```
map(lambda d: d.pop('item'), apps)
```

And you will get same `apps` as above.

Comment: thanks, please see my revised *apps* above. How would I get the revised *apps* to be like: [{'category': 'two'}, {'category': 'three}, {'category': 'one'}]   NOT: [{'category': 'two', 'item': 'blah'}, {'category': 'three', 'item': 'blah'}, {'category': 'one', 'item': 'blah'}]

Comment: You want to delete all 'item' key and just want to show 'category' key and value? I will update answer! Hope helping!